# Initializing a Set to a AlpineJS local variable

Tags: javascript, set, alpine.js

Is it not possible to do assign a `Set` to a variable in AlpineJS ?

```
x-data="{ show: {} }" x-init="show = new Set('a', 'b', 'c')"
```

I'm trying to replace native array code with the help of sets.

```
@click="this.event.target.checked ? show.push(key) : show.splice(show.indexOf(key))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define empty Set() in x-data and add elements with x-init.
You can also add the whole Set in x-data

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

 <div x-data="{ show: new Set() }" x-init="() => { show.add('a'); show.add('b'); show.add('c'); }">
  <template x-for="item in Array.from(show)">
    <label>
      <span x-text="item"></span>
    </label>
  </template>
</div>



<div x-data="{ show: new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']) }">
  <template x-for="item in Array.from(show)">
    <label>
      <span x-text="item"></span>
    </label>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I see this working - I just couldn't see the alpineJS dev tool having the set data updated.